# Rcpp::compileAttributes() not updating .R file

Tags: r, package, rcpp

I am trying to build a package in R involving the `Rcpp` package. When I generated the package using the command `Rcpp.package.skeleton("pck338")`.

By default, the files `rcpp_hello_world.cpp` is included, and the `RcppExports.cpp` file is included as well.

To my understanding, the `compileAttributes()` function needs to be run *every* time a new `.cpp` function is added to the `src` directory.

To that end, I wrote a simple function in the `rcpp_dance.cpp` file that goes like this:

```
# include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp:export]]
int rcpp_dance(int x) {
  int val = x + 5;
  return val;
}
```

However, when I run the `compileAttributes()`, the `RcppExports.cpp` stays the same, so the dance function is not converted to an R function. Why is this happening? Any specific and general feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a case like this where it smells like a possible error, check for a possible error. I learned (the hard way) to first assume I goofed...

In your case: `::` != `:`.

You wanted `Rcpp::export` with two colons.  Try that, rinse, repeat...

(And for the other conjecture: you need to re-run `compileAttributes()` each time *an interface* changes: adding or removing or renaming or retyping an argument in the signature, and of course adding or removing whole functions.  But thankfully the function is so fast that you may as well get in the habit of running it often.  If in doubt, run it.)

Comment: Sigh, it's the small mistakes that get you! Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome.  As I said: _been there, done that_.  Computers can be annoyingly deterministic as do as we _told them_ rather than as we meant to say.